# how to get click events on plotly.js table?

Tags: javascript, charts, plotly, plotly.js

I trying to get the click event on the table cell of plotly.js table.
I just want to console.log('clicked cell name'), but it seems nothing is getting fired no matter what I do.

please help I'm stuck for a few days now.

```
let make_table = (id)=>{
        var values = [
                ['Salaries', 'Office', 'Merchandise', 'Legal', '<b>TOTAL</b>'],
                [1200000, 20000, 80000, 2000, 12120000],
                [1300000, 20000, 70000, 2000, 130902000],
                [1300000, 20000, 120000, 2000, 131222000],
                [1400000, 20000, 90000, 2000, 14102000]]
          
          var data = [{
            type: 'table',
            header: {
              values: [["<b>EXPENSES</b>"], ["<b>Q1</b>"],
                                           ["<b>Q2</b>"], ["<b>Q3</b>"], ["<b>Q4</b>"]],
              align: "center",
              line: {width: 1, color: 'black'},
              fill: {color: "grey"},
              font: {family: "Arial", size: 12, color: "white"}
            },
            cells: {
              values: values,
              align: "center",
              line: {color: "black", width: 1},
              font: {family: "Arial", size: 11, color: ["black"]}
            }
          }]

        Plotly.newPlot(id, data)
              .then(g => {
                g.on('plotly_click', d => {
                  console.log(d)
                })
              })
}
```

for eg. If I click on cell with value == 1200000, then I want to perform console.log(1200000).

Comment: What is `g` in `g.on('plotly_click', ...)`?

Comment: it's graph reference variable. for eg. Plotly.newPlot(id, data) will return a plotly_graph object.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=How%20to%20create%20a%20Minimal%2C%20Complete%2C%20and%20Verifiable%20example.